# how do I get size of preexisting circularly shaped layer in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, creative-cloud

I am new to photoshop (Adobe Photoshop CC) and not finding it very intuitive. How do I get the radius of a preexisting circle in photoshop? Someone sent me an editable psd, and I have the circle as a layer. Also is there a way to resize a circular layer to give it a larger radius or would I just need to recreate the circle?

Thanks very much for any help or tutorials you can point me towards.

Answer (score 2):

Well if its a Liveshape then you can just look at the Properties panel:

[image: Live Shape Properties]

If it's a Raster shape then you're in luck that you said its on its own layer, though its not too hard to find the edges even if it wasn't. On its own layer, hold ctrl and click the thumbnail in the layer panel. That will select the circle for you indicated by a marquee. Then go to Window → Measurement Tools and you can click `Record Measurements`. You can also go into the Measurement Log preferences to change Units and Scale. In Measurement 3 you see I have it in Pixels, in Measurement 4 I changed to Inches using 300ppi:

[image: Raster Circle Measurement using Measurement Tools]

Just the Measurement Log panel:

[image: Measurement Log Panel]

Answer (score 0):

Going along with @Ryan, here is some info on how to resize objects using the transform tool.

Use the transform tool. Select the layer in the layers panel that has the circle object on it (Note: if the layer has more than just the circle then everything in that layer will be transformed). If you do not see the layers panel go to windows -> layers. Press ctrl + T on windows, apple + T on Mac to use the free transform tool. Hold shift to keep the same perspective and hold alt to scale from the original spot.

You can also find these options under edit -> transform -> free transform.